# Two threads + InvokeMember on different files = NullReference?

Tags: c#, multithreading, reflection

So I have 2 different threads: thread1 and thread2, running with the following methods:

```
public static void thread1()
{
    Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("t.dll");
    Type t = asm.GetType("dis.Code");
    Object Res = t.InvokeMember("Start", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, null, null);

}
public static void thread2()
{
    Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("test.dll");
    Type t = asm.GetType("dis.Code");
    Object Res = t.InvokeMember("Start", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, null, null);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to invoke 2 different files "t.dll" and "test.dll". They're both lying in the same directory as the .exe file containing the program above. The only thing the .dll files do, is a simple Console.WriteLine.

So here's the problem: Calling one file with 1 or both threads results in success and will post the Console.WriteLine twice. However, once I call the 2 different files, 1 file with each thread, I end up with a NullReferenceException in the second call.

This is all coded in C#.
Please help :(

Comment: where do you exactly get the exception?

Comment: The exception comes at the last "Object Res = t.InvokeMember("Start", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, null, null);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [extern alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx) and [namespace alias qualifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad.aspx) to load types belonging to different assemblies but with same namespace.

This has been explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/11/30/498278.aspx) and [Using two .NET libraries with the same namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740991/using-two-net-libraries-with-the-same-namespace).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem because you have the same type names "dis.Code" in different assemblies?
And when you try to load second assembly it fails and return null